# Paypal REST SDK integration in Expressjs not showing transactions in Sandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've integrated Paypal REST sdk in my Expressjs application. I'm connecting it with Angular app.

Here's the code I've written:

```
router.post('/buy' , ( req , res ) => {
    const amt = req.body.quantity*req.body.price

    /**
     * Paypal payment json to be passed
     */
    const payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "https://localhost:4200/success",
            "cancel_url": "https://localhost:4200/err"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "total": '' + Math.round((amt)*100)/100,
                "currency": "CAD",
                "details": {
                    "subtotal": '' + Math.round((amt)*100)/100,
                    "tax": "0.00",
                    "shipping": "0.00"
                }
            },
            "description": "This is payment description.",
            "item_list": { 
                "items":[
                    {
                        "quantity": req.body.quantity, 
                        "name": "collection", 
                        "price": '' + req.body.price,  
                        "sku": req.body.collid, 
                        "currency":"CAD"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }]
    }

    /**
     * Paypal payment object created
     */
    paypal.paypal.payment.create(payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send({message: error})
        } else {
            console.log('payment:', payment)
            for(let i=0; i<payment.links.length; i++) {
                if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url') {
                    res.json({forwardLink: payment.links[i].href});
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

While doing transactions, it is doing successful transaction and landing me to `https://localhost:4200/success` page. But I'm unable to see the transactions in [sandbox](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/) account. There's no deduction of money and so no transactions are shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old, deprecated v1 SDK.  And you are missing the required 'execute' API step which must occur after approval and being redirected to the return_url.

---

You should switch to a current v2 integration with [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK). The API calls you need are 'Set Up Transaction' and then after approval 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

The best web flow to use for the approval is here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , as it involves no redirects and keeps your site loaded in the background

Comment: Can you refer me to a guide which follows v2 in Express-Angular app? I'm stuck at Express side. I've followed client side for v2 but don't know how to integrate the same with server side